# How to get the selected item from Primeng Panelmenu

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using Panelmenu from Primeng. When someone clicked to an item in this Panelmenu, I want to get that item.

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display">
    <p-panelMenu [model]="sidebarItems" [style]="{'width':'280px'}"></p-panelMenu>
</p-sidebar>
```

For example, if someone choose the Apartment option from below, I want to get it. How can i achieve this?

```
this.sidebarItems = [
      {
        label:'Home',
        icon:'pi pi-fw pi-home',
        routerLink: '/home',
        items: [
          {label:'Apartment',
          icon:'pi pi-fw pi-home',
          routerLink: '/apartment',}
        ]
      },
      {
        label:'Contact',
        icon:'pi pi-fw pi-phone',
        routerLink: ['/contact'],
      },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add commands to every menu item that would save the active item:

```js
activeItem: MenuItem;
...
{
  label: 'Contact',
  icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-phone',
  routerLink: ['/contact'],
  command: e => this.activeItem = e.item,
}
```

You can also apply this to every item and sub item of the menu:

```js
 private fixupItems(items: MenuItem[]): void {
   items?.forEach((item) => {
     item.command = (e) => (this.activeItem = e.item);
     this.fixupItems(item.items);
   });
 }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-panelmenu-demo-2hwq6r?file=src/app/app.component.ts)